# PHP: should I be writing all my code in classes?

Tags: php, oop, class

I've been coding with PHP for a while now, but I've been mainly coding with Functions and raw PHP.

I've started to think that I should be writing my code a whole lot neater and more efficiently. I still can't quite get my head around classes. Should I be writing ALL my code in classes?

For example, one of my scripts is a 'permissions manager' - which allows an admin to edit the permissions of various user groups on the site.

Traditionally, I'd have written this as just a script with functions and whatnot. But would it better to write this as a class? If so, what would this class contain? Would I have a separate permissions class for use around the site, and another for the admin-editing area?

Also the site has an API. Should this all be written as one class?

Also, should I be using public (shared) functions at all?

Thanks!

Comment: You should get a book on OO design, and consider how to apply it to web development.  Sticking your code in a class won't magically make your code more organized.  This topic is much too broad to be answered in a question here.

Comment: I think this kind of discussion is better suited to chat. OOP is great in the right context but to answer the question in short, "should you be writing *all* your code..." probably not - you can over-engineer a problem.

Comment: My answer would be yes, but this isn't a question with a single answer, so this is not the right place for this discussion.

Comment: The problem here is that procedural programming (what you've been doing so far) and object orientation are just different styles, and we can't really tell you which one to chose without knowing _exactly_ what you are building. And chances are that even if we knew all the specifics, the choice would still be in the realm of personal preferences, thus completely up to you. Object orientation is fun, but it's not a silver bullet, and it's definitely not a "must have".

Comment: To make matters even more complicated, even if you chose to go the OOP way, we can't really tell you what your classes should contain without having a very good idea of your project. Software design is an incredibly complex process, and we need all the information you can give us or we'll probably send you to the wrong path. My advice would be to write your code in an OOP way, finish it, and then post it on [Code Review Stack Exchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/), our sister site for peer reviews.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion everything depends on how large is your project. I've worked using Magento for a while and it's so big that it must be grouped in classes and packets. It's easier to read code and analyse the structure of project if it's split in classes. Also when you need to modify your project after a month or year then good structure helps to re-learn it.

Answer (score 1):

It is useful to write stuff in Classes when a particular set of functions and variables belonging and/or oriented to the same entity or propose is to be used in different environments. It gives a sense of organization, delegation of tasks and avoids repetition of code.

But in situations where the above is false, it is completely disposable. Theres no point in writing a class to something that will run only in one specific place.

Also, if you only want to have a set of information organized in an object-like style like in `$user->name`, `$user->age` etc. you can simply do this:

```
$user = (object)array(
    'name' => 'John',
    'age'  => 20
);
```

Comment: Re your last code snippet, why bother casting to an object? PHP arrays can do everything a classless object like that can, often more efficiently.

Comment: Mostly just for the looks. Code becomes more readable.

Comment: Meh. Matter of taste, I guess, but `$user['name']` reads fine to me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in my point of view it would be better to make your code in `OOP` to be more neat, understandable, readable and also for maintenance it will be more easy, 
Please take a look here in this stack  :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4409824/what-are-the-advantages-of-object-oriented-php

Answer (score 0):

You should approach that question from a different angle. Don't just use OOP because you think you have to.

Ask yourself:

1. Are there parts of my application that I could reuse in other parts of my application? Then these could be taken out of your script and be put in a function or class.
2. Is there a scenario where you would like to exchange parts of your code to change the behaviour without having to rewrite major parts of your application? Then classes and interfaces are for you.

Another good argument for using OOP principles is the increased testability of your code. Using interfaces allows you to exchange the actual object for a mock or stub at test time.